# What is missing from the code to make the treeview work?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, treeview

The following problem makes me crazy, for the last 2 days i spent my afternoons trying to solve the problem, so i really tried to research it.

My problem is that, when i'm using databinding to a treeview, it doesn't seem to work. I'm probably missing something, and i'd like to kindly ask your help finding it.

For the WPF XAML i'm using the following code:

```
<Window x:Class="MesDiag2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MesDiag2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Materials}" DataType="{x:Type local:ProductNode}">
        <Label Content="{Binding Product.LotName}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Root}">

    </TreeView>


</Grid>
```

My classes are the following, note that this is only a "test" project i made to see where the problem is. I've tried to make everything as simple as possible. The INotifyPropertyChanged for every class was just a desperate attempt to see if it fixes it:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MesDiag2
{
    public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string lotName;
        public string LotName
        {
            get { return lotName; }
            set
            {
                lotName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LotName");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

The context of the TreeViewItem should be the following class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MesDiag2
{
    public class ProductNode : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Product product;
        List<Product> materials;

        public ProductNode(Product product)
        {
            Materials = new List<Product>();
            Product = product;
        }

        public Product Product
        {
            get { return product; }
            set
            {
                product = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Product");
            }
        }

        public List<Product> Materials
        {
            get { return materials; }
            set
            {
                materials = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Materials");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MesDiag2
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ProductNode Root { get; set; }
        public string Test { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Root = new ProductNode(new Product { LotName = "Test" });
            Test = "Hello";
        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the content of my MainWindow class:

using System.Windows;

```
namespace MesDiag2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Root` is one single object, not a collection. `TreeView.ItemsSource` must be bound to a collection. Either bind it to `Root.Materials`, or make `Root` a collection with one `ProductNode` in it. If that collection, or `Materials`, is going to gain or lose or reorder items after the TreeView is populated, it should be `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`. `ObservableCollection` will notify the TreeView when items are added, removed, or reordered.

Comment: Maybe the datatype should be product rather than productnode. Why would a collection of product be called anything but products? Why is there a productnode at all though? Are you exposing a model class directly to the view?

Comment: I'm making a product-material scenario. I want my product class to store information only about a product. For example, if you have a car, you say it can go from 0 to 100 in 5 seconds, but in fact, some of it's matrials makes the car do it, but sometimes you only want to know the car can go from 0 to 100 in 5 seconds. On the other hand, materials are products too. If a factory's product is the engine, it's material in the next factory where they put it in the car.

I need information about the product, as a whole, and its' materials as different beings, but handling them as products too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been a little while since I've done WPF, but I think you want to do something like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Root.Materials}">
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <Label Content="{Binding LotName}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

I'd also make:

```
 List<Product> materials;
```

this:

```
 ObservableCollection<Product> materials
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: To clarify, i want to do it, but with the Root element included. The Root element wasn't a collection, thus treeview couldn't handle it.

Comment: Edited my response to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: Also prefer to make your List<> object an ObservableCollection<>